# What is the mime type application/encrypted?

Tags: python, ms-office, mime-types

Python magic detects the mime type "application/encrypted" for password protected microsoft office documents. But I am unable to find any information about this mime type on the internet. It is not even listed at https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
Is this even a valid mime type?
And if I wanted to check if a file is a protected office document is checking for this mime type a reliable method?
This is the code I am using: magictype is "application/encrypted" after.

`import magic`
`magictype = magic.Magic(mime=True).from_file(filepath)`

Comment: you probably did some web scraping. Hiwever you are not mentioning why it is a prblem in what code area. Probably you want to ask such question in the python forum ?

Comment: The problem is: I am looking for a way to tell if a file is a protected office document. My idea is that this mime type might tell me so but I dont find any information on it.

Comment: that is standard microsoft style. You will find unddocumented stuff all over there. However it might be documented when you would tell us which api you are using exactly !?

Comment: i added the code that is producing the weird mime type to my question

Comment: still don't know what the document source ist. I would assume that mimetype is unspecific for a reason there for you can#t expect to know what document is inside with such a mime type in fron

Comment: Oh thats what you wanted to know, sorry. The document source is simply my MS Word application encrypting a docx file. The confusing thing is that the MIME type is not only generic but not listed anywhere.

Comment: if you google for that you will find many examples where the purpose is always obfuscation. Sorry can't help here